# Does VS2010 or .NET 4.0 have any new tooling support for Accessibility?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, accessibility, section508, wcag

What kind of tooling support or helpers does VS2010 or .NET 4.0 provide to developers in the way of accessibility?

- Anything new for creating 508-compliant markup?
- Anything new in the way of supporting WAI-ARIA specific attributes on AJAX-updatable elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some links, if you have not already seen them:

[ASP.NET Controls and Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227996.aspx)

[Accessibility in Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2009/07/31/accessibility-in-visual-studio-2010-and-asp-net-4.aspx)